# Matplotlib and non-ascii characters

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib

Never ending story about Matplotlib and non-ascii characters continues, indeed:

1) Localhost: Mac OS X: By default, some characters are missing (replaced with []). OK, after adding `matplotlib.rc('font', family='Verdana')` characters are displayed fine. However, when deploying to a production server things get broken once again.

2) Server: Linux (openSUSE, using: `matplotlib.use('Agg')`, serving png's and pdf's, Django app): Calling `matplotlib.rc('font', family='Verdana')` does not help now (WHY?). I even copied some core fonts from Mac to openSUSE to make sure they are the same.

What does help a bit is this:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
fp = fm.FontProperties(fname="/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Verdana.ttf") 
# matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = fp.get_name()
matplotlib.rc('font', family=fp.get_name())
```

and then using per partes `plt.title(_title, fontproperties=fp)` for each plot/block. This is very tiring… And what is worse, it is not usable when working with legends. For example there is no way (is there?) to use it like that:

```
ax.legend([charts], [_label], fontproperties=fp)
```

and

```
ax.legend([charts], [_label], prop={'family': 'Verdana'}
```

does not have any effect (it works on Mac OS X, though).

Funny thing is that most of non-ascii characters are displayed fine (ščřž…), problems occur only with ě, ť, ď… Why is Matplotlib still having these issues with unicode? I would not mind back in 90's but it is 2015 and not being able to use diacritics properly is pain.

Why do the “hooks” work under OS X, yet do not have any effect in openSUSE server?

Comment: It is an issue of the system not finding the right font.

Comment: I nailed it down to the server, that's for sure now. Because I moved this project also to my second laptop with openSUSE on it and it all works as expected, both in dev server and Apache. So it must be server related. Have no idea what is wrong, though. The server is not running Xorg, not installed there. And I found out that Freetype was installed just yesterday.

Comment: you may need to re-run the system level `fc-cache` and remove where mpl is keeping it's font cache (`import matplotlib.font_manager as fm` then `fm.cachedir`  Delete everything in that file and try again).

Comment: Thank you, you opened my eyes, man. Because you made me think: I blindly kept deleting cache in `/root/.cache/...` but that is not the right place to look, as the server is not run under root, omfg. Well, I printed the cache path as a plot title and bang: `/var/lib/wwwrun/.cache/matplotlib`. After deleting this folder and also `fontconfig` folder in the same path things work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib not finding the correct fonts can be caused by stale font cache (this is a problem we need to solve better).

To find were your cache is do

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
print(fm.cachedir)  # or other way of getting the text out
```

And then delete the font-related contents in that directory.  They will be rebuilt the next time you import matplotlib and (should) now contain the updated fonts.